# Unable to get header value with custom Authorization in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have implemented a Custom Authorization in ASP.net Web API project (not asp.net core) as below

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public class AuthorizeFilterAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext httpContext)
        {
            foreach (var item in httpContext.Request.Headers)
            {
                string skey = item.Key;
                var val = item.Value;
                Debug.WriteLine(skey + "-" + val.ToString()); //On this line I get the value for custom header "SecurityToken"
            }
            //The below line returns NULL
            var key = httpContext.Request.Headers.Where(z => z.Key == "SecurityToken").FirstOrDefault(); 
            //The below lines also return value as NULL
            httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("SecurityToken", out IEnumerable<string> authorizationToken);
            string securityCodes = Convert.ToString(httpContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("SecurityToken").FirstOrDefault());
            bool tryGetValue = httpContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("data", out object data);
            
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I use the same code in my Controller function as below, I am able to get the Header values

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Home/GetBanners")]
    public APIResponse GetBanners()
    {
        //Able to get values here
        string code = Request.Headers.GetValues("SecurityToken").First();
    }
}
```

The major problem is when I try calling the API using POSTMAN, the custom authorization passes the tests but same call when I make from my front end app, it fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a stale thread but still...

You need to override the AuthorizeCore method and put your headers logic in there, e.g.:

```
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // your custom headers logic goes here...
        return true;
    }
```